# DOS. Print number of characters read | int 21h, ah = 0Ah

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I am new to learning assembly language. I have the following code to read a string with a five character limit.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    message    db "Type a word: ", '$'

    keyboardArea label byte
    maxkeys    db 5
    charsInput db ?
    buffer     db 32 dup(0)
.code
    main proc
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

        mov dx, offset message
        mov ah, 9h
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset keyboardArea
        mov ah, 0Ah
        int 21h

        mov ah, 4Ch
        int 21h
    main endp
end
```

How can I print the number of characters read?

Comment: [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075) covers the general case, but your input limit is only 5 (despite reserving 32 bytes in the buffer), so `charsInput` will always be a single-digit number.  So just load it and `add dl, '0'` for a print-char DOS call.

Comment: Ok, I tried to load the offset of charsInput in the DX register as with the other variables, then, I wrote what you put in your comment (add dl, '0') to then use mov ah, 2h; int 21h but when I run, it always prints the letter 'A' as the first letter, no matter what word I write (it overwrites the "T" of the variable printed at the beginning, "message"). Am I skipping something or where should I load charsInput? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to load the byte from memory, not its address.  `mov dl, [charsInput]`.

Comment: You just saved me, I really appreciate it.